# Method to display list of available portlets in a portlet

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

Generally `liferay` has `ADD` option for displaying available portlets.

I want them to appear in a drop-down and that should be in a custom plugin-portlet, so I am searching in API which method is retrieving the available portlets, but I didn't find any.

Please help me in this as I am stuck with this and also on selecting from the drop-down the portlet should be added to the page.

Comment: There is no need of adding signature in your question. Also learn to use the formatting to improve the readability of your question.

Answer (score 1):

The "Add...More" dialog is displayed by the dockbar portlet. You can find the implementation of the UI part of this in Liferay's source in `portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/dockbar/add_panel.jsp`, which also includes `view_category.jsp` in the same directory.

While this jsp code is not the prettiest, you'll easily find that [`PortletLocalService`](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/PortletLocalServiceUtil.html) is the one where you find the relevant information, together with an actual sample of how to access the list of portlets by category, sort them according to the current user's locale etc.

As you're asking for more concrete pointers: In `add_panel.jsp` you can find:

```
for (PortletCategory curPortletCategory : categories) {
    if (curPortletCategory.isHidden()) {
        continue;
    }
    request.setAttribute(WebKeys.PORTLET_CATEGORY, curPortletCategory);
    request.setAttribute(WebKeys.PORTLET_CATEGORY_INDEX, String.valueOf(portletCategoryIndex));
    %>
    <liferay-util:include page="/html/portlet/dockbar/view_category.jsp" />
    <%
    portletCategoryIndex++;
}
%>
```

and some excerpts from `view_category.jsp`:

```
<%
PortletCategory portletCategory = (PortletCategory)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.PORTLET_CATEGORY);
int portletCategoryIndex = GetterUtil.getInteger((String)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.PORTLET_CATEGORY_INDEX));
// ...
Set<String> portletIds = portletCategory.getPortletIds();
// ...
for (String portletId : portletIds) {
    Portlet portlet = PortletLocalServiceUtil.getPortletById(user.getCompanyId(), portletId);

    if ((portlet != null) && PortletPermissionUtil.contains(permissionChecker, layout, portlet, ActionKeys.ADD_TO_PAGE)) {
        portlets.add(portlet);
        // ... and so on
```

Hope this excerpt helps. See the rest of the file for what you can actually do with the resulting list. Also, [Portlet](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/model/Portlet.html)'s interface might help if you need more details.

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer. I didnt find any thing useful that works for my requirement.